# How to get title of landmark place from Wikipedia by API?

Tags: c#, json, regex, wikipedia-api

For my code I am using the Wikipedia API which provides links to all places that are linked with the Wikipedia article of that city. But with my code there are some extra unnecessary links. I want to only return links where the type is "landmark".

My Wikipedia API is:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json
```

Sample JSON data from the Wikipedia API:

```
"query": {
    "geosearch": [
        {
            "pageid": 5858187,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Stuttgart Hauptbahnhof",
            "lat": 48.783888888889,
            "lon": 9.1816666666667,
            "dist": 136.8,
            "primary": "",
            "type": "railwaystation",
            "name": "",
            "dim": 1000,
            "country": "DE",
            "region": "BW"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 6102287,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Staatstheater Stuttgart",
            "lat": 48.780277777778,
            "lon": 9.185,
            "dist": 361,
            "primary": "",
            "type": "landmark",
            "name": "",
            "dim": "900",
            "country": "DE",
            "region": "BW"
        },
        {
            "pageid": 35806545,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Versatel building",
            "lat": 48.78409,
            "lon": 9.17799,
            "dist": 400.4,
            "primary": "",
            "type": null,
            "name": "",
            "dim": 1000,
            "country": null,
            "region": null
        },
        {
            "pageid": 3230957,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Neue Staatsgalerie",
            "lat": 48.780277777778,
            "lon": 9.1869444444444,
            "dist": 430.6,
            "primary": "",
            "type": "landmark",
            "name": "",
            "dim": 1000,
            "country": "DE",
            "region": "BW"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

My code to get the `Title` from this API.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content;
        string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList();

        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the current output:

[image: Output]

How can I get the title from the results where the `type` is "landmark"?

Comment: Perhaps, using `Where`? `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Where(p => p.type == "landmark").Select(a => a.title).ToList();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use JSON format, try this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch
    .Where(a => a.type == "landmark").Select(a => a.title).ToList();
```

Also you can get all titles without to use Json.NET. This is how I do it with XML format:

```
using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Create("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type&format=xml").GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var response = XElement.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
        var obj = response.Descendants("gs")
            .Where(a => a.Attribute("type") != null && a.Attribute("type").Value == "landmark")
            .Select(a => a.Attribute("title").Value).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# :-)

But try something like this:

```
var geosearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch;
var landmarks = geosearch.Where(type => type == "landmark");
```

Comment: Well, the "Where" method just does the filtering, you need to work with the resulting output